# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Previewing a Dojo hybrid app displays a blank page

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am developing a Hybrid application in Worklight 6.1 using Dojo 1.9.3. As a startup i just created a simple project with a View and a scrollable view.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>index</title>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
            <script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="mainView"
        data-dojo-props="selected:true" style="background-image: url('images/bgnew.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat;">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view1"
            data-dojo-props="selected:true,scrollDir:'v'">
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
                data-dojo-props="label:'Login',fixed:'top'">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

After creating building and deploying the project i tried to Run it by clicking "`Preview as Common Resources`" link. But unfortunately nothing displays on my screen. I checked my browser console i can see no error showing.

Dojo is already present in my `www` folder.

How to solve this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you make to use Dojo 1.9.3? Because AFAIK Worklight 6.1 includes Dojo 1.9.1 so there might be some issue on your project setup. Could you provide your detailed project creation steps and (if possible) a copy of your project?

Comment: I replaced Dojo 1.9.3 with the default 1.9.1 and it worked.But i just included Dojo 1.9.3 while creating project ( by selecting Add Dojo Library option).

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce. I've done the following in Worklight 6.1.0.0:

1. Created a new Worklight project
2. Added an application with the Dojo library (using the provided wizard)
3. Right-click on the Common folder > Run As > Preview

The browser opened, displaying the app.

The same worked if opening Worklight Console and selecting Preview as Common Resources.

Tested on OS X 10.9.2
Chrome as default external browser (Eclipse > Preferences > General Web Browser > use external web browser)

Comment: It is working if i create a new project without adding anything new in my index.html file..But if i add any widgets in my html file it wont display anything...

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me today, and I found a solution : 
Use the default Dojo provided by the IBM Worklight (actually the 1.9.1 ) instead of the 1.9.3
When I tried to import and use the 1.9.3, it did the same thing than the original poster. I think it is not already supported or there is a problem we do not think about during the importation.